# How to clone(deepcopy) java linkList

Tags: java, linked-list, clone

I am implementing clone of my linkList which is written without LinkList from library. 
My code is shown below:

```
public class myNode implements Cloneable {

    private class1 obj1;
    private myNode next;
    //---- some immutables....
    public object clone(){
        try {
             myNode cloneNode = super.clone();
        }
        catch (ClassNotSupported ex){
        }
        cloneNode.obj1 = this.obj1.clone();//This is implemented.
        cloneNode.next = this.next.clone();
        return cloneNode;
    }
}
```

Now the result of my clone method is coming out to be a stackoverflow. 
For eg. if my myNode linkList looks like:

> "aa"-->"bb"-->"cc"-->"dd"-->"null"

Then once I call clone on my head of the linkList which is not shown here, (in my test function) then clone of linkList spirals into an infinite loop and looks like:

> "aa"-->"bb"-->"aa"-->"bb"-->"aa"-->.....

What am I messing up here. Can someone please help.

Comment: shouldn't you be checking `next` for `null` before `cloneNode.next = this.next.clone();`?

Comment: I am checking for it. Not written here to keep it simple.

Comment: SInce you are recursively calling `clone()` on successive nodes, if there are a lot of nodes you will get stackoverflow exception.

Comment: can you please post the code to add new nodes to the list?

Comment: `this.next.clone(); and this.obj1.clone(); ` because of these lines. these are making your method as recursive method.

Comment: instead of cloning you can use copy constructor or copy factory method.

Comment: To simplify the problem, I have reduced the number of nodes to 4. (Avoiding stackoverflow) and I want the code to be recursive.

Comment: Thanks all. It was my bad somewhere in the code. Put a debugger and found out. I had messed up something. I was also creating a graph in that class1. Messed up some node creation and was going round and round.

Answer (score 0):

there is problem in your clone method you can simply edit your code as:

```
public object clone(){
        try {
             myNode cloneNode = (myNode)super.clone();
              cloneNode.obj1= class1.clone();
        }
        catch (ClassNotSupported ex){
        }
        return cloneNode;
    }
```